# raspberry pi3 b+ slideshow program not working

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi3

I wanted to turn my raspberry pi into a slideshow device but I barely know python 3 could anyone help me fix this code I found online? It's supposed to display the images in the list I created but it doesn't run. The only changes I made to this code was the creation of the list so I have no idea why it does not work. The error I'm getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bro.py", line 82, in <module>
    slideshow.start()
  File "bro.py", line 56, in start
    self.main()
  File "bro.py", line 48, in main
    self.set_image()
  File "bro.py", line 42, in set_image
    self.image_name = next(self.images)
StopIteration
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Display a slideshow from a list of filenames"""

import os
import tkinter

from itertools import cycle
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


class Slideshow(tkinter.Tk):
    """Display a slideshow from a list of filenames"""
    def __init__(self, images, slide_interval):
        """Initialize

        images = a list of filename 
        slide_interval = milliseconds to display image
        """
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("+0+0")
        self.slide_interval = slide_interval
        self.images = images
        self.set_images(images)
        self.slide = tkinter.Label(self)
        self.slide.pack()

    def set_images(self, images):
         self.images = cycle(images)

    def center(self):
        """Center the slide window on the screen"""
        self.update_idletasks()
        w = self.winfo_screenwidth()
        h = self.winfo_screenheight()
        size = tuple(int(_) for _ in self.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x'))
        x = w / 2 - size[0] / 2
        y = h / 2 - size[1] / 2
        self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x, y))

    def set_image(self):
        """Setup image to be displayed"""
        self.image_name = next(self.images)
        filename, ext = os.path.splitext(self.image_name)
        self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(self.image_name))

    def main(self):
        """Display the images"""
        self.set_image()
        self.slide.config(image=self.image)
        self.title(self.image_name)
        self.center()
        self.after(self.slide_interval, self.start)

    def start(self):
        """Start method"""
        self.main()
        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    slide_interval = 2500

    # use a list
    images = [
              "/~/definitely/1550099164562.png",
              "/~/definitely/1550770995551.png",
              "/~/definitely/1550771217013.png",
              "/~/definitely/1550771726391.jpg"]

    # all the specified file types in a directory 
    # "." us the directory the script is in.
    # exts is the file extentions to use.  it can be any extention that pillow supports
    # http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html
    import glob
    images = glob.glob("*.jpg")
    path = "."
    exts = ["jpg", "bmp", "png", "gif", "jpeg"]
    images = [fn for fn in os.listdir(path) if any(fn.endswith(ext) for ext in exts)]

    # start the slideshow
    slideshow = Slideshow(images, slide_interval)
    slideshow.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `next(iter(images))` instead of `next(images)`.

BTW, I have Raspberry Pi slideshows for both Tkinter and Kivy on my tachyonlabs GitHub ... they also download photos from Instagram, but if you don't hook that up or there's no Internet connection they will just cycle through the images in the image directory you specify, with your chosen order and duration.